# AJAX call doesn't happen without alert on specific computer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

So I have the weirdest problem, in my company's CMS we have a newsletter system that does an AJAX call to send an e-mail. Now this works perfectly in all modern browsers on all operating systems, however it does not for one client.

This client is using Windows 7 and IE9, I have Windows 7 myself and tried IE9 (even with all compatibility modes) but it would always work.

I don't know why it doesn't work for them, however I was able to "fix" it by placing an `alert` before and inside the AJAX call.

I am thinking it must be something with their hardware or connection, and was hoping somebody might have an explanation. Here is the AJAX call (with the alerts) so you can see there is nothing wrong (right?):

```
$('#send_single').unbind().click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    processing();               
    alert('one');

    $.post(
        'newsletter/ajax.php', 
        {   
            action: 'send_single', 
            email: $('#single_email').val(), 
            template: $('#select_template').val(), 
            id: $('#select_newsletter').val()
        }, 
        function(data) {
            alert('two');
            finished_processing();      
            cmsalert(data);
        }
    );
});
```

`processing()` fades in a processing box, which `finished_processing()` then removes. Without the alert boxes the `finished_processing()` never happens, with the alertboxes it runs as expected.

**processing()** and **finished_processing()**

```
function processing(){

    $('#full_overlay').fadeIn();
    $('#processing').fadeIn();

}

function finished_processing(){

    $('#full_overlay').fadeOut();
    $('#processing').fadeOut();

}
```

`#full_overlay` is a fullscreen fixed div with a white overlay. `#processing` is a centered div containing a loading gif and a "Please wait..." string.

`finished_processing()` doesn't happen, so I don't think `cmsalert()` is in any way related. (cmsalert slides in a div at the bottom of the page containing a - usually success - message)

Comment: what does cmsalert() do ? im guess its related to animation or displaying something on the screen that causes the finished_process() method not to be visible(i bet its running)

Comment: Can you post the code for `processing()` as well?

Comment: We'll probably need to see `processing` and `finished_processing`. What do you see when you open the developer tools? IE9 has a reasonable set of debugging stuff.

Comment: I take it just one alert or the other doesn't "fix" it?

Comment: May be it is a slower computer, that highlight an asynchronous error in your code. You may not notice it on fast computers.

Comment: I haven't actually tried removing `alert('one');` but it's very possible it works without that. I had to fix it over the phone within a short amount of time. I will be adding the code of the other functions, even though I don't think it should matter.

Comment: @Mic, that is something I considered, is there a way to fix this without using alertboxes?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sadly enough I don't have the option since I can't visit the client. Developer tools on my system don't show any problems, but I have never encountered any here anyway..

Comment: @Kokos: If you can get on the phone to the client, you should be able to tell them to press F12 and walk them through telling you what they see. It isn't fun, but it sounds like it's the only way you'll get to the bottom of this. Not seeing any issues with the quoted code. Also, you say `finished_processing` doesn't happen, but how do you *know* that? Since it's a fade, it happens over a period of time; `cmsalert` may well be causing something to stop all JavaScript on the page, including the subsequent loops on the fadeout.

Comment: @Kokos, when lost like that, I use `console.log(1)`, then 2, 3... from the start, and compare with a working computer. At a moment the chain of logs will differ.

Comment: @Mic, at first I put in 6 different alerts, they all happened for them. The difference was that the alert after the AJAX call occured before the ones within the call. T.J.Crowder I am lost in IE9 developer tools compared to Firebug, any clues as to where I should (tell them) to look?

Comment: Btw. The comment of Mic about 'asynchronous error' is more likely to be related to slow internet connection than a slow computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the example show in the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/promise/#example-1), changing your  finished_processing function like:

```
function finished_processing(){

    $('#full_overlay').promise().done(function() { this.fadeOut(); });
    $('#processing').promise().done(function() { this.fadeOut(); });

}
```

You may also face problems if the client clicks several consecutive times, keep that in mind. I believe the return of `$.post()` can also be used in the same lines (`$.post().promise()` or `$.post().done`) in case you could store in a variable and use that. You may also like to have a look at [Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).